# unexpected symbol in R please see the code

Tags: r, symbols

I was trying to write a function to parse and merge some data. But R throws an unexpected symbol error exception. I have tried different ways to solve this issue, still doesn't work. Please help.

see code

```
$aggall = function(df,grp){numcols = sapply(df,class) %in% 
c('integer', 'numeric') result = aggregate(df[,numcols],df[grp],mean) 
 counts = as.data.frame(table(df[grp])) names(counts)[1] = 
 grp merge(counts, result, sort=FALSE)}
```

Error: unexpected symbol in "aggall = function(go,grp){numcols = sapply(go,class) %in% c('integer','numeric') results"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have your whole function in one physical line.
Therefore, when `R` tries to parse it, it has no way of knowing when one line ends and the next one begins.

To fix this, either use separate lines or add a semicolon between them.

---

**Alternatively, you can have the `formatR` package do it for you!**
(pretty awesome package):

```
install.packages("formatR")
library(formatR)
tidy.source("mySource.R", reindent.space=5)


aggall = function(df, grp) {
     numcols = sapply(df, class) %in% c("integer", "numeric")
     result = aggregate(df[, numcols], df[grp], mean)
     counts = as.data.frame(table(df[grp]))
     names(counts)[1] = grp
     merge(counts, result, sort = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: This is so wasteful of space.

Comment: @TylerRinker so a scrambled mess of code is a good thing? last i checked, doing that incurred the wrath of the code review gods (and also the senior developers) and made them smite you. With perl.

Comment: @Hiroto, I think Tyler may have been being facetious, but I can't tell.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta neither can I. The OP should really learn to make his code readable, though.

Comment: My apologies it was an attempt at humor.  I guess not that funny.

Comment: Maybe the comments parser couldn't handle the `<\irony>` markers?